# add integer to NSMUtableArray

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsmutablearray, integer, uipopovercontroller

I am a new iPad developer.

I am implementing UIPopover on button click, and popover contains integer value,

when i trying to fill my array with integers it shows me, `SIGABRT`: **index 3 beyond bounds** i am unable to see my log, app crashes.

here is my code snippet:

```
-(void)btnClick:(id)sender {

    for (int i=3; i<=31; i++) {
        [remindarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
         NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 0, 500, 4)];

    popoverTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 665) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [popoverTable setDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)self]; 
    [popoverTable setDataSource:(id<UITableViewDataSource>)self]; 
    [self.view addSubview:popoverTable];
    [popoverTable release];

    [popoverView addSubview:popoverTable];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250, 600);
    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                              initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

    [self.popoverController  presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100,0, 535, 35) 
                                             inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];

    [popoverView release];
    [popoverContent release];
}
```

and finally `remind array` i am passing to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

code:

```
...
cell.textLabel.text=[remindarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
...
```

Comment: i think what thrown the exception is this line NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i]);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your for loop starts from 3, so in the array starts by 0 items, then you insert 1 item and you try to log the item at index 3, which is still not inside the array

A quick fix is by

Change

```
NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i]);
```

to

```
NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i - 3]);
```

Or by starting the array from 0

Also you will need to change

```
cell.textLabel.text=[remindarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [remindarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: when i write `cell.textLabel.text=[remindarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in tableview my app crashes.

Comment: selected index of the table? fetch it where?

Comment: yes selected index of popover table and want to store in string.

Comment: but what if i want to fetch text of selected row in popover ? not index sorry it was my mistake.

Comment: What do you mean text, what does your table contain?

Answer (score 2):

Because newly created array index started from `0` index not from `3`

The problem is in this loop

```
for (int i=3; i<=31; i++) {
        [remindarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
         NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

Comment: when i write `cell.textLabel.text=[remindarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in tableview my app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=3; i<=31; i++) {
    [remindarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
     NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Here you are starting i with 3 and you are assigning single object to remindarray so at first it contains only one object so objectAtIndex:3 will be nil so modify the code like this

```
NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i-3]);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think what thrown the exception is this line

```
NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i]);

//
-(void)btnClick:(id)sender {
for (int i=3; i<=31; i++) {
    [remindarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
    //your remindArray has one object, index is 0, but you are accessing the 
    //object which is at the index of 3, but the remindArray
    // has only one object [0]
     NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: you add an object at index 0 of the array, and then you want to print the object at index 3.
Use:

```
NSLog(@"no=%@",[remindarray objectAtIndex:i - 3]);
```